# How can I import app from __init__.py and why I'm getting this error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, import, importerror

I want to import `db` from `__init__.py` int the `model.py` file but I can't import, an error appears that says:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rohit/Desktop/flask_app/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bytewar import create_app
  File "/home/rohit/Desktop/flask_app/bytewar/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bytewar.user.views import user_blueprint
  File "/home/rohit/Desktop/flask_app/bytewar/user/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from bytewar.model import Login_form, Login, Post, Contacts, Signup_form, Contacts
  File "/home/rohit/Desktop/flask_app/bytewar/model.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bytewar import db
ImportError: cannot import name 'db'
```

**My application tree:**

```
___ run.py     # <<------- ImportError in this file.
___ bytewar/
  |__ __init__.py
  |__ config.py
  |__ model.py       
  |__ user/
  |   |__ __init__.py
  |   |__ views.py
  |   |__ static/
  |   |    |__ img/
  |   |    |__ ....
  |   |__ template/
  |       |__ index.html
  |       |__ about.html
  |
  |__ admin/
      |__ __init__.py
      |__ views.py
      |__ template/
          |__ index.html
          |__ about.html
```

**__init__.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap 
from flask_login import LoginManager
from bytewar.user.views import user_blueprint
from bytewar.admin.views import admin_blueprint

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask('bytewar')
    app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True

    app.register_blueprint(user_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'

    return app
```

Here you can see I've `db.init_app(app)` but still I'm getting `ImportError`.

**After adding `__init__.py` file inside the `bytewar.user/` and `bytewar.admin/`(beside `views.py`), I'm getting error in `run.py`:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rohit/Desktop/flask_app/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bytewar import app
  File "/home/rohit/Desktop/flask_app/bytewar/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bytewar.user.views import user_blueprint
  File "/home/rohit/Desktop/flask_app/bytewar/user/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from bytewar.model import Login_form, Login, Post, Contacts, Signup_form, Contacts
  File "/home/rohit/Desktop/flask_app/bytewar/model.py", line 5, in <module>
    from run import db
  File "/home/rohit/Desktop/flask_app/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bytewar import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

**run.py:**

```
from bytewar import app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**My `bytewar/user/__init__.py` and as it is `bytewar/admin/__int__.py`:**

```
from flask import Blueprint

user_blueprint = Blueprint(
    'user', __name__,
    static_folder='static',
    template_folder='template',
 )
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

In `bytewar.user.views` you import db from your `__init__.py`. That however is only defined a few lines below the import. So at the time the import is done,  db does not exist yet, which the error confirms. When you look at the example code for application factory [1](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/#the-application-factory) you see that the `app` variable is only used after it is defined, your code should do that too. Move your imports to the bottom and you are set.

As an aside: Why do you create your `app` in the factory and immediately overwrite it? Leave the second creation out.

Comment: Please, Would you define in code for me to better understand?

Comment: Is my `__init__.py` and the application tree structured well or not? If not so what is the efficient way to do that. Make me understand.

Comment: I didn't understand the example, which provided you by link!

Comment: The link is to the documentation. Your ´__init__.py´ is not correct. move the imports from ´bytewars.user.views´ and ´bytewars.admin.views´  down to the end of the function as per the advice.

Comment: And why I need to move my `__init__.py'` to `user/` folder. I had one `__init__.py` and I deleted that because my flask wasn't detecting `style.css` files and still I'm getting same issue. You can look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59783877/why-flask-not-detecting-changes-in-my-flask-application-and-user-login-route-i). I would be thankful of you.

Comment: Please ......, Could you provide me little code of this question because I'm little confusing. How it gonna work?

Comment: I'd create two `__int_.py` separate inside `bytewar.user` and `bytwar.admin`. Inside `__init__.py` I created `Blueprints` one for user, admin but now I start getting `ImportError: cannot import name 'app'` in `run.py` to start application. What should I do now?

Comment: Of you have another question, create a new one. Did you search for structure on SO Flask questions ? There are several.

Comment: It didn't resolve my error of this question. Now I'm getting error in `run.py`